# Get RSA private key and certificate from GlobalSign certificate

Tags: certificate

I can generate my own private key and certificate as follows:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048

openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out g4certificate.pem -days 1095
```

Copy+pasting the certificate/private key parts into a database and executing a test toolkit returns a successful HMAC key exchange.

However, I've now purchased a GlobalSign ssl certificate and have the .pfx file.

How can I extract the equivalent RSA private key/certificate similar to those used when the toolkit returned a successful key exchange?

My attempt:

I tried to convert the .pfx file to a .pem file using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in filename.pfx -out filename.pem
```

The resulting .pem file contains 3 certificates and a private key with a header of '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' and not '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'.

I've tried to copy+paste the private key out into a new document and saved it as privatekey.key. Then converted it using the following command:

```
openssl rsa -in privatekey.key -out privatekey_new.key
```

This produces a file with the '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' header which is like the self-generated RSA key.

However, when attempting the key exchange, I get the following error:

```
DEBUG [AbstractTest] - Failed: 
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1674)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1580)
```

Comment: I would take this up with GlobalSign's customer support. It sounds like you bought the wrong type of cert for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

> Wrong key usage

It means that the certificate cannot be used for thing you are trying to.